# Ruby Thin app in Docker

Tags: ruby, docker, thin

I am trying to build a Docker image of Ruby application based on Thin server. First, let me show you my dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7.4.1708
WORKDIR /opt/myapp
ENV PATH=/opt/myapp/ruby/bin:${PATH}
ENV GEM_HOME=/opt/myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0
CMD /opt/myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/bundle exec thin -C /opt/myapp/config/thin.yml start
EXPOSE 9292
```

The directrory "myapp" contains all gem dependencies as well as Ruby binaries. After building the image, I try to run the image:

```
docker run -d myapp:latest
```

The image shuts down immediately after starting.

Docker logs output:

```
Starting thin myapp...
Starting server on 0.0.0.0:9292 ...
```

Docker ps -a output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
081e3d6fa8c1        99880f8f67d4        "/bin/sh -c '/opt/my…"   3 seconds ago       Exited (0) 2 seconds ago                       cocky_bohr
```

However, when I run the same image with Bash command:

```
docker run -it myapp:latest bash
```

and then start the server using exactly the same command as in dockerfile's CMD, the application starts and run as expected.

This is what I don't understand. Any help will be appreciateed. Thank you!

Comment: what does `docker logs` show for that container after it exits?

Comment: Show us your `config/thin.yml`. Make sure that you don't run thin daemonized.

Comment: Here is my thin.yml:

`---
user: myapp
group: myapp
pid: /opt/myapp/tmp/thin.pid
timeout: 30
wait: 30
log: /opt/myapp/log/server.log
max_conns: 1024
require: []
environment: development
max_persistent_conns: 512
servers: 1
no-epoll: true
daemonize: true
port: 9292
tag: myapp`

However, when I change "daemonize" to false and rebuild the image, the app behaviior does not change.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is pretty old, but I just faced the exact same problem and adding `--threaded` option to thin seems to have solved it.